# padded border or hr on the bottom of each row

Tags: html, css

Is there an easier way, without any sort of hacks, to get it to visually look like this (a bottom border that is padded 10px from each side) without having to create an extra row just for it?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5">
    <hr style="border-bottom: solid 1px #000; padding: 0 10px"/>  
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <hr style="border-bottom: solid 1px #000; padding: 0 10px"/>  
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  It seems to me that removing the padding won't create a problem.

Comment: So basically, you want to achieve the same result, but with less HTML?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not styling your table with divs?

Comment: Which of those 2 tables is the effect you're going for?

Comment: I've updated the post, I want the first table, with less code.

Comment: You should precisify what you mean by "without any sort of hacks". I mean, you do consider all the answers hacks, right?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but here's a table that looks the way your example does, only without a nested table.
Is this roughly what you're after?

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  background: #eee;
  width:20%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left: 10px solid #eee;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 10px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it is, so pretty much you're just tricking it with a fake 10px border on the sides?

Comment: Good answer. Just add border-collapse and set the border only on nth-last-child(n + 1) and it will match exactly the request

Comment: @vals Pfff, the question has been edited many times. My answer reflects the second revision; see edit history.

Comment: You are right. , your result is ok. For me, your answer should be accepted. (And I absolutely agree with your comment on the question, what does exactly mean **any sort of hacks** ?)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you imply by hacking. But this is a way i could get it done. I hope you find it useful.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
td:first-child:before {
  left: 0;
}
td:last-child:after {
  right: 0;
}
td:first-child:before, td:last-child:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
}
tr:last-of-type td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use pseudo element to generate empty 10px width cells on each sides .

```css
table {
  background: lightgray;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width:100%;
}

td {
  padding:0.5em  1em;
}

table tr td {
/* draw borders Hr like via border-style or a mix with border & shadow */
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 white
}

/* remove fake hr from first-row */
table tr:first-of-type td {
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0
}

tr:before,
tr:after {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[pen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LyZoXG)

[second pen with padding also on td](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NjrQQp) --> hr drawn on tr's bacground.

---

**you are using pseudo for something else ?**

Make it simple instead complicated.

- set padding on table itself

```css
table {
  background: lightgray;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
  padding:0 10px;
}

td {
  padding:0.5em  1em;
}

table tr td {
/* draw borders Hr like via border-style or a mix with border & shadow */
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 white
}

/* remove fake hr from first-row */
table tr:first-of-type td {
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[pen to play with](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bWeyXK)

- or set borders to table

```css
table {
  background: lightgray;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
 border-left:solid transparent 10px;
 border-right:solid transparent 10px;
}

td {
  padding:0.5em  1em;
}

table tr td {
/* draw borders Hr like via border-style or a mix with border & shadow */
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 white
}

/* remove fake hr from first-row */
table tr:first-of-type td {
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- or you can draw it via `background` and `background-size`

```css
table {
  background: lightgray;
  border-spacing: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px; /* or use pseudos */
}

td {
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

table tr {
  background: linear-gradient(black, black) top center no-repeat, linear-gradient(white, white) center 1px no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(100% - 20px) 1px;
  /* for a 20px padding */
}

table tr:first-of-type {
  background: none;
}


/* next is a guess */

td:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

td:last-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}


/* see padding */

td:nth-child(odd) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: with the first technique, let's say I want the line to start where the word starts, how would I do that as setting padding to the tr also affects the td which I want to have a padding of 10px on each side? adding 10px to the row would then have the word start at 20px from the table.

Comment: @totalnoob increase width of pseudo an avoid left padding on first td , then right padding on last cell i guess. do you have a running code to see exactly what have ? how many cellls, padding on each and so on

Comment: @totalnoob  another method would be to draw the border via bg & bg-size .... https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NjrQQp

Comment: A great answer ! (supplying lots of alternatives)

Answer (score 1):

I was working on something today and wanted to do exactly what was posted here. I remembered what i posted but decided to try another way.
What i did was put the background color on the table itself. Targeted the first and last "td" of every row and made them a block element.
I was able to apply a margin to them. Then i had an issue with the targeted "td"s. They weren't aligning with others. I fixed that by negating the position "bottom: -1px". See below. I guess this is another way

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
tr td:last-of-type, tr td:first-of-type {
    display: block;  
    bottom: -1px;
}
tr td:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
tr td:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
tr:last-of-type td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this method,The HTML code has been minimized from 31 lines to around 20 lines.You need to define a Table Border only once in the CSS part and call it as many times as you want in the HTML table.

```css
 

table{
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
background: #eee;
}

#border {
border-bottom:   1px   #000 solid;
border-left:  0 10px   #eee solid;
border-right: 0 10px   #eee solid ;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="border">
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>e</td>
 </tr>

<tr id="border">
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>e</td>
</tr>

<tr id="border">
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
<td>e</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code with less html and css:

```
table {
 border-collapse:collapse;
 width: 100%; 
}

td {
 background: #eee;  
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 padding:5px 10px
}

tr:last-child td{
 border-bottom:none
}

<table>
 <tr>
 <td>a</td>
 <td>b</td>
 <td>c</td>
 <td>d</td>
 <td>e</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>a</td>
 <td>b</td>
 <td>c</td>
 <td>d</td>
 <td>e</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>a</td>
 <td>b</td>
 <td>c</td>
 <td>d</td>
 <td>e</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
table.rowborder{
 border-collapse:collapse;
 width: 100%; 
}
table.rowborder tr td{padding:10px 0;}
table.rowborder tr{border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;}
table.rowborder tr:last-child{border-bottom: 0px transparent solid;}
```

```html
<table class="rowborder">
 <tr>
 <td>a</td>
 <td>b</td>
 <td>c</td>
 <td>d</td>
 <td>e</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>a</td>
 <td>b</td>
 <td>c</td>
 <td>d</td>
 <td>e</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>a</td>
 <td>b</td>
 <td>c</td>
 <td>d</td>
 <td>e</td>
</tr>
</table>
```